# Как запретить переход по ссылке?

Tags: jquery, javascript, html, php

Есть такая конструкция `<a href="link.php"><img src='pic.jpg'></a>`, когда нажимаю на картинку, то естественно происходит переход по ссылке, как это запретить? 
п.с. только не надо вот такое `<a href="#">` изображать. Вопрос в том, что делать когда ссылка уже существует и кликается строго по изображению в ссылке, а не по самой ссылке.

Вот код как есть:

```
$('a img.killer').on('click',function(e){
     var drName = $(this).attr("name"); 
      alert(drName);
      e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Ссылка:

```
<a href='http://test.ru'>
 <img class='killer' name='kivi' src='pic.gif'>
 test
 </a>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$("a img").click(function(){
    //действия
    return false;
});
```

Кстати, а так:

```
$("a img").parent().click(function(){
    return false;
});
```

Comment: ****
    $("a img").click(function( e ){
        e.preventDefault();
    });

Comment: Разница в них есть? Просто я  первый раз вижу эту функцию. А описании написано, что оно отменяет действие наложенное на элемент по умолчанию.

Comment: увы, не срабатывает ни то, ни другое.

Comment: @Ёхарный Бабай - разница в тоам как вы пишите. return false - большет похоже на магию, `preventDefault()` говорит само за себя, учитывая то что еще и контекст вызова этого метода - event object, это, ИМХО, понятнее.

Такой метод есть, например, в библиотеке prototype, да и потом - такой метод есть и в нативной реализации, вот [линк](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.preventDefault). Как вы наверное понимаете, в большей степени, это дело вкуса.

@Tolbase - значит вы что-то делаете неправильно, ответы вам дали верные
****
[jquery API link](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

Comment: Попробуйте вызвать эти коды после остальных скриптов, возможно там есть что-то, что перехватывает.

Comment: кроме того что добавил в вопрос ничего нету, как и alert'a, так и вывода в консоль чего-либо что говорило бы об ошибке.

Comment: Значит сработал селектор.

Comment: в принципе сделал, пришлось немного серверный скрипт изменить, добавил аттрибут perehod к ссылке и его читал на false/true, parent() таки помог.

Comment: я вас прекрасно понимаю, но все загружается, по факту я просто не могу физички кликнуть до того как страница загрузилась, написал выше что parent() помогло, да, так и есть, но alert'a нету там где пометил "Код как есть".

Answer (score 0):

```
<a class="disabled" href="link.php"><img src='pic.jpg'></a>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.disabled').on('click', false);
});
```